# How can I set device mode via networkd

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge, dev

How can I set mode to device (for example monitor/ap to wlan) via networkd deamon in .link file ???

Because I want to set bridge in .network of wlan device and I can't do it until I set it in specific mode.

```
##################################
# /etc/systemd/network/eth0.link # 
##################################
[Match]
MACAddress=xxxxxxxxxx

[Link]
Description=Top Ethernet Port
Type=ether
Name=eth0
#MACAddressPolicy=persistent 
MACAddress= rewrite mac 
WakeOnLan=off

#####################################
# /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network #
#####################################
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Address]
Address=192.168.0.101/24
Broadcast=192.168.0.101

[Network]
Bridge=br0

###################################
# /etc/systemd/network/br0.netdev #
###################################
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
MACAddress=set mac

####################################
# /etc/systemd/network/br0.network #
####################################
[Match]
Name=br0

[Address]
Address=192.168.0.100/24
Broadcast=192.168.0.100

[Network]
Description=Default network through bridge
Gateway=192.168.0.1
DHCP=ip4
IPv6PrivacyExtensions=true
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4

[DHCP]
UseDNS=false

[Bridge]

[Route]
#Gateway=192.168.0.1
#Destination=192.168.0.0/24
#Scope=link

###################################
# /etc/systemd/network/at0.link   #
###################################
[Match]
# See: udevadm info /sys/class/net/at0
Type=wlan
OriginalName=wlan0
#MACAddress=
Driver=ath9k

[Link]
Description=Top Wireless Lan Port
Name=at0
Type=wlan
MACAddress= rewrite mac
BitsPerSecond=100M
WakeOnLan=off

####################################
# /etc/systemd/network/at0.network #
####################################
[Match]
Name=at0

[Address]
Address=192.168.0.102/24
Broadcast=192.168.0.102

[Network]
Bridge=br0            <---- THIS FAILS
```

#

```
$ networkctl 
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     configured
  2 eth0             ether              routable    configured
  3 at0              wlan               no-carrier  configured
  4 br0              ether              routable    configured


$ networkctl status 
●      State: routable
     Address: 192.168.0.101 on eth0
              192.168.0.102 on at0
              192.168.0.100 on br0
              fe80::cb4:a1ff:fea2:111 on eth0
              fe80::cb4:a1ff:fea2:110 on br0
     Gateway: 192.168.0.1 (Cisco SPVTG) on br0
         DNS: 8.8.4.4
              8.8.8.8
```

ps.

I know how create bridges and interfaces through networkd and how add interfaces to bridge - but what i dont know is how to change mode of particularly interface (wireless nic) to other mode without using wpa supplicant or iw / iw conf

from : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd

> Wireless adapter
>
> In order to connect to a wireless network with systemd-networkd, a
>   wireless adapter configured with another service such as
>   wpa_supplicant is required. In this example, the corresponding systemd
>   service file that needs to be enabled is
>   wpa_supplicant@wlp2s0.service.

But I don't want to connect! I want to make ad-hoc - ap

so I want to:

- set for example mode to ap/monitor (promiscuous mode)
- set wpa essid
- set wpa key